# Were there two Black Neuroi Hives?

Tags: strike-witches

At the end of *Strike Witches*, not only did the Warlock destroy all the Neuroi (including the humanoid one), but after the Warlock's destruction, the Black Neuroi Hive disappeared.

However, at the start of *Strike Witches 2* which begins slightly before the final scene of the previous season (where Yoshika receives a second letter from her father), the 504th is sent to a Black Neuroi Hive where a Humanoid Neuroi was waiting in a hope to strike peace with the Neuroi. However, the Humanoid Neuroi was destroyed by an attack from the Green Neuroi Hive and subsequently, the Black Hive is never seen again.

Now the second season affirms the ending of the first season (Gallia being freed, the Warlock turning into a Neuroi and losing control), so I am wondering was there two Black Neuroi Hives and if so, where was the second one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes, there's another Black Neuroi Hive that was destroyed at the beginning of *Strike Witches 2.***

According to a more general question asking the total number of hives on [Yahoo! Chiebukuro (Japanese)](https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q12100997307), which was answered by mr_hungry01:

> The new hive that occurred at the beginning of season 2, episode 1 is right above Venezia facing the Adriatic Sea.
>
> At the same time, the destroyed hive was displayed on the screen as if it was on the city facing the sea, **but in setting it is said to be "Hive of the South Karlsland"**. Together with the fact that the 504th use this strategy against Neuroi crossing the Alps mountains until it was destroyed, **it seems it's around in the inland north of the Alps mountains**.
>
> <sup>(partial answer focusing on the 2nd season only, emphasis mine)</sup>

The [Wikia](http://strikewitches.wikia.com/wiki/Neuroi) also mentions this:

> As of 1945, Neuroi hives have been confirmed in the following regions.
>
> - [...]
> - **South Karlsland** - apparently located near the Rhine river, destroyed by a stronger hive that later established itself in Venezia;
> - [...]